# Find the kernel of the linear transformation mapping $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $k:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ be defined via $[x, y]\mapsto [x − y, 3y]$. Find the kernel of $k$.

My initial thought is to make this a matrix by coordinates
$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 \,&\!\!\!\! - 1  \\
   0 \,& 3  \\
\end{array}} \right]
$$
as columns and augment it with $[x,y]=[0,0]$. But, this only works if the matrix will reduce to the identity, correct? I am not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: What you have to do is solve the system $$x-y=0\\3y=0$$ easy to solve.

Comment: so the single solution would be the kernel? @Piquito

Comment: In general a transformation's kernel might contain only the single vector zero, or might be a subspace of infinitely many vectors (but can be described by a spanning set). Solving a system of equations can also give either exactly one solution or many related solutions.

Comment: yes... but can you be specific to this problem? I understand the concept. @aschepler

Comment: For example, the linear mapping in your example has trivial kernel $\{0\}$, but the linear mapping of the linear space on $\mathbb{R}$, $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ , $\varphi(x,y)=x$ obviously has kernel $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$. You may have learned, or will learn the following theorem: $V$ and $W$ are linear spaces over field $\mathbb{F}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, then a linear mapping $\varphi: V\rightarrow W$ has kernel with dimension $\dim ker\varphi=\dim V-rank(A)$, $A$ any matrix of the linear mapping $\varphi$

Comment: but is it true that the kernel is just the solution to the system x-y=0,3y=0? @Asigan

Comment: @belushi1 That is right. The kernel of the linear mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (x-y,3y)$ is definitely the solution of $x-y=0, 3y=0$, namely $(0,0)$. To prove this fact, you merely need to recall the definition of ‘kernel’, as well as note that $(0,0)$ is the zero element ( or zero vector) in the linear space $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @belushi 1: YES, but this is (very) important because it shows that $k$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of $k$ is the set of vectors $(x,y)$ such that $k(x,y) = 0$. That is the definition of the kernel of a linear transformation. Hence the kernel is the set op points (x,y) such that

$$ x - y = 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad 3y = 0.$$

This gives us a system of linear equations whose solution is the set

$$ \ker k = \{ (0,0) \}.$$